# How to update a record conditionally with a field value in the same record in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table where the user can update their information. And for now I use the query to perform the update:

```
UPDATE `bdusertable` SET `name`= ?, `nickname`= ?, `gender`= ?, `birthday`= ?, `email`= ?, `password`= ?  WHERE `usercod`= ?
```

But I have an account verification scheme. I must prevent the user from updating some of the data when the account is verified.

The verification field may have 3 values:

```
0 = not verified
1 = verified by a moderator
2 = verified by an administrator
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE `bdusertable` SET (`name`= ?, `gender`= ?, `birthday`= ?) IF `verified` = 0 , `nickname`= ?, `email`= ?, `password`= ?  WHERE `usercod`= ?
```

As long as the user is not verified, he can update any field. 
But if verified, you can not change the most important fields.

can anybody help me?

Comment: this is something you could handle in the application which is calling the database. And then run a different query based on that. Or you could use a series of CASE statements as suggested in the duplicate

Comment: @Loveless I found the example of your link somewhat complicated, but I'll try to understand how this works and try to adjust for my case. Thank you.

Comment: @ADyson If I have a way to do it directly in SQL I think it would be easier, but I will study several ways. Thank you

Comment: How should the UPDATE query know if the user, mod or admin is changing the most important fields i wonder.. Like @ADyson said this is a privilege system and you should implement that in the application code

Comment: @ADyson The link answer was successful. Thank you.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, the answer of the link that the \@ADyson indicated went right. Thank you.